# Is there a way to return all unique values within a given row

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working in Oracle SQL and I have a data set with these headers
[image]
In this data set card number is unique, however, the customer can have duplicates in their Suggestion fields. Rather than going through and writing case statements, is there a way to keep only the unique values within the given row?

Please note, some customers will be left with more "unique" suggestions than others

For example:
[image: SAMPLE DATA]

My goal would be for my final output to look like this
[image]

As I have mentioned, previously, I would just write case statements saying

```
SELECT DISTINCT CARD_NUMBER
    ,SUGGESTION_1
    ,CASE 
        WHEN SUGGESTION_2 != SUGGESTION_1
            THEN SUGGESTION_2
        WHEN SUGGESTION_3 != SUGGESTION_1
            THEN SUGGESTION_3
        WHEN SUGGESTION_4 != SUGGESTION_1
            THEN SUGGESTION_4
        WHEN SUGGESTION_5 != SUGGESTION_1
            THEN SUGGESTION_5
        END AS SUGGESTION_2 
    CASE 
        WHEN SUGGESTION_2 != SUGGESTION_1
            AND SUGGESTION_3 != SUGGESTION_1
            AND SUGGESTION_3 != SUGGESTION_2
            THEN SUGGESTION_3
```

`

I would do this until all unique values are left, and there just has to be an easier way
Any help would be EXTREMELY appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all` and conditional aggregation.  Here is the idea that puts the results in a single column:

```
select card, listagg(suggestion, ', ') within group (order by which) as suggestions
from (select card, suggestion, min(which) as which
      from ((select card, 1 as which, suggestion_1 as suggestion from t) union all
            (select card, 2, suggestion_2 from t) union all
            (select card, 3, suggestion_3 from t) union all
            (select card, 4, suggestion_4 from t) union all
            (select card, 5, suggestion_5 from t)
           ) t
       group by card, suggestion
     ) t
group by card;
```

You can do something similar with conditional aggregation if you want the values in separate columns.

Comment: this is great! But yes, the values in separate columns would be perfect

Answer (score 1):

I would try to pivot the table to long, and then back to wide

Setup:

```
create table testtbl
(
  CARD_NUMBER    int
  ,SUGGESTION_1  varchar2(100)
  ,SUGGESTION_2 varchar2(100)
  ,SUGGESTION_3 varchar2(100)
  ,SUGGESTION_4 varchar2(100)
  ,SUGGESTION_5 varchar2(100)

  );

insert into testtbl values (1234,'G11','G4','G3','G2','G6');
insert into testtbl values (5678,'G4','G6','G6','G11','G6');
insert into testtbl values (9101,'G1','G3','G11','G4','G11');
```

Then the Query itself, first the pivoting to long. Here I use a function just to return the numbers from 1 to 5 - this is instead of joining the table 5 times to itself, this way it should only pass through the test table once.

I then use the analytical functionrow_number to sort the unique values according to their first placement.

The second select uses MAX to pivot back to wide

```
with cte AS
(
SELECT
    CARD_NUMBER
    ,MIN(n.column_value ) n
    ,CASE n.column_value 
        WHEN 1 THEN f.SUGGESTION_1
        WHEN 2 THEN f.SUGGESTION_2
        WHEN 3 THEN f.SUGGESTION_3
        WHEN 4 THEN f.SUGGESTION_4
        WHEN 5 THEN f.SUGGESTION_5
    END Suggestion
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY f.CARD_NUMBER ORDER BY MIN(n.column_value)) rn
FROM testtbl f
CROSS JOIN  table(sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3,4,5)) n
GROUP BY f.CARD_NUMBER,CASE n.column_value 
        WHEN 1 THEN f.SUGGESTION_1
        WHEN 2 THEN f.SUGGESTION_2
        WHEN 3 THEN f.SUGGESTION_3
        WHEN 4 THEN f.SUGGESTION_4
        WHEN 5 THEN f.SUGGESTION_5
    END
)
SELECT 
CARD_NUMBER
,MAX(CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN Suggestion ELSE '' end)SUGGESTION_1
,MAX(CASE WHEN rn=2 THEN Suggestion ELSE '' end)SUGGESTION_2
,MAX(CASE WHEN rn=3 THEN Suggestion ELSE '' end)SUGGESTION_3
,MAX(CASE WHEN rn=4 THEN Suggestion ELSE '' end)SUGGESTION_4
,MAX(CASE WHEN rn=5 THEN Suggestion ELSE '' end)SUGGESTION_5
FROM cte
GROUP BY CARD_NUMBER
ORDER BY CARD_NUMBER
```